# How to replace all lines starting with string '#' inside block with ansible replace module

Tags: regex, ansible

I am trying to remove all lines starting with "#" after a line starting with "# END" and before the first line starting with a char [a-z] using ansible buildin module replace.
The problem for me seems to be that this 'replace' module does not use the 'multiline' option for Python regular expressions with for its functions 'before' and 'after'.

I am using ansible 2.9 (on Red Hat Satellite Server).

Contents of file to edit

```
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
# this line should stay
# this line should stay, too
# so should this line
#
# username1:1000000:199000
# username2:1200000:199000
# username3:1400000:199000
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
# some comment here which should be removed
# some more comment also to be removed
#
# username1:1000000:199000
# username2:1200000:199000
# username3:1400000:199000
# 
# this should be the last line to be removed
userabc:1000001:65536
```

Ansible task

```
- replace:
    path: /etc/subuid
    after: '# END ANSIBLE'
    before: '^[a-z]*'
    regexp: '^# [ \S \w]*\n'
```

Expected resulting file content

```
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
# this line should stay
# this line should stay, too
# so should this line
#
# username1:1000000:199000
# username2:1200000:199000
# username3:1400000:199000
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
userabc:1000001:65536
```

Comment: I finally found a regular expression for the option "regexp" which removes each line with a match:   `- replace:
    path: /etc/subuid
    after: '# END ANSIBLE'
    before: '^[a-z]*'
    regexp: '^# [ \S \w]*\n'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
---
- name: stackoverflow
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name : Removeing lines
    replace:
      path: /home/vagrant/abcd
      after: '# END ANSIBLE[.]*'
      regexp: '#(.)*'
      replace: ''
  - name : Removing emptyline
    replace:
      path: /home/vagrant/abcd
      after: '# END ANSIBLE[.]*'
      regexp: '(^\s*$)'
      replace: ''
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggested solution. It does the job. But in the meantime i found the right "trick" to do it with one replace task. Said trick is to include the line-break in the regex to the "regexp" option so tha each line with a match is replaced or rather removed in this case.